# How do I incorporate a websocket connection between cozmo robot and a hololens?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, websocket, ros, hololens

I'm using ROS Python library with [cozmo](https://www.anki.com/en-us/cozmo) and I want to use the information that I get from back from him to interact with him in AR using a Hololens. From what I know I need to establish a connection using websocket with [cozmo](https://www.anki.com/en-us/cozmo) and the hololens. I don't know how to incorporate WebSocket with Unity.

If anyone knows of any resources I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/simple-web-sockets-for-unity-webgl-38367.

Even though it says "for WebGL" on the package title, I used it in an Android app connecting to a Python WebSockets server, and used the same code in a Windows executable.
Should work on Hololens too.